# Where TYPO3 is storing the "not in menu" state of pages?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Having a page with state "not in menu". In which table and which field TYPO3 stores this information? I need it for a manual select query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All pages are stored in atable named... `pages` field you are looking on is `nav_hide`.

Tip: you can check it yourself using ie. inspector tool of your browser, just click element, inspect it and check its name attr, it's `data[pages][123][nav_hide]`, where 123 is uid of the record